# Best approach to compare if one list is subset of another in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below two classes:

```
public class FirstInner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
}
public class SecondInner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }            
}
```

Again, there are lists of those types inside the below two classes:

```
public class FirstOuter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<FirstInner> Inners { get; set; }
}
public class SecondOuter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }         
    public List<SecondInner> Inners { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have list of `FirstOuter` and `SecondOuter`. I need to check if `FirstOuter` list is a subset of `SecondOuter` list.

Please note:

1. The names of the classes cannot be changed as they are from different systems.
2. Some additional properties are present in `FirstOuter` but not in `SecondOuter`. When comparing subset, we can ignore their presence in `SecondOuter`.
3. No.2 is true for `FirstInner` and `SecondInner` as well.
4. List items can be in any order---`FirstOuterList[1]` could be found in `SecondOuterList[3]`, based on Id, but inside that again need to compare that `FirstOuterList[1].FirstInner[3]`, could be found in `SecondOuterList[3].SecondInner[2]`, based on Id.

I tried Intersect, but that is failing as the property names are mismatching. Another solution I have is doing the crude `for each` iteration, which I want to avoid.

Should I convert the `SecondOuter` list to `FirstOuter` list, ignoring the additional properties?

---

Basically, here is a test data:

```
var firstInnerList = new List<FirstInner>();
firstInnerList.Add(new FirstInner
{
    Id = 1,
    Type = "xx",
    RoleId = "5"
});
var secondInnerList = new List<SecondInner>();
secondInner.Add(new SecondInner
{
    Id = 1,
    Type = "xx"
});
var firstOuter = new FirstOuter 
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "John",
    Title = "Cena",
    Inners = firstInnerList
}
var secondOuter = new SecondOuter
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "John",
    Inners = secondInnerList,
}
var firstOuterList = new List<FirstOuter> { firstOuter };
var secondOuterList = new List<SecondOuter> { secondOuter };
```

Need to check if `firstOuterList` is part of `secondOuterList` (ignoring the additional properties).

Comment: Did you mean check 1st list record is a part of 2nd one?

Comment: How about ;
   `var isSubset = !firstOuterList.Select(s => <properties that match with other list>).Except(secondOuterList.Select(s => <properties that match with other list>)).Any();`

Comment: yes @KiranJoshi

Comment: you can check through a specific field. like `var lst= firstOuterList.Where(y=>secondOuterList.Any(z=>z.Id==y.Id));` is it ok for you

Comment: Either create anonymous types with the properties you want to compare (like @vikscool showed you) or implement a IEqualityComparer and use `Except`

Comment: I'm not 100% on how `Sets` work, but there's an `IsSubsetOf` method in there, which if you were to override the default `object.Equals` on your classes, you could possibly leverage.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1.issubsetof?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `foreach` way that I have is:

```
foreach (var item in firstOuterList)
        {
            var secondItem = secondOuterList.Find(so => so.Id == item.Id);
            //if secondItem is null->throw exception
            if (item.Name == secondItem.Name)
            {
                foreach (var firstInnerItem in item.Inners)
                {
                    var secondInnerItem = secondItem.Inners.Find(sI => sI.Id == firstInnerItem.Id);
                    //if secondInnerItem is null,throw exception
                    if (firstInnerItem.Type != secondInnerItem.Type)
                    {
                        //throw exception
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //throw exception
            }
        }
        //move with normal flow
```

Please let me know if there is any better approach.

Comment: is the answer gives you proper output that you want?

Answer (score 0):

First, do the join of firstOuterList and secondOuterList

```
bool isSubset = false;
var firstOuterList = new List<FirstOuter> { firstOuter };
var secondOuterList = new List<SecondOuter> { secondOuter };

var jointOuterList = firstOuterList.Join(
      secondOuterList,
      p => new { p.Id, p.Name },
      m => new { m.Id, m.Name },
      (p, m) => new { FOuterList = p, SOuterList = m }
);

if(jointOuterList.Count != firstOuterList.Count)
{
      isSubset = false;
      return;
}

foreach(var item in jointOuterList)
{
      var jointInnerList = item.firstInnerList.Join(
                 item.firstInnerList,
                 p => new { p.Id, p.Type },
                 m => new { m.Id, m.type },
                 (p, m) => p.Id
      );

      if(jointInnerList.Count != item.firstInnerList.Count)
      {
                isSubset = false;
                return;
      }
}
```

**Note: I am assuming Id is unique in its outer lists. It means there will not be multiple entries with same id in a list. If no, then we need to use group by in above query**

Answer (score 0):

I think to break the question down..

- We have two sets of Ids, the Inners and the Outers.
- We have two instances of those sets, the Firsts and the Seconds.
- We want *Second's* **inner** Ids to be a subset of *First's* **inner** Ids.
- We want *Second's* **outer** Ids to be a subset of *First's* **outer** Ids.

If that's the case, these are a couple of working test cases:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ICanSeeWhenInnerAndOuterCollectionsAreSubsets()
    {
        HashSet<int> firstInnerIds = new HashSet<int>(GetFirstOuterList().SelectMany(outer => outer.Inners.Select(inner => inner.Id)).Distinct());
        HashSet<int> firstOuterIds = new HashSet<int>(GetFirstOuterList().Select(outer => outer.Id).Distinct());
        HashSet<int> secondInnerIds = new HashSet<int>(GetSecondOuterList().SelectMany(outer => outer.Inners.Select(inner => inner.Id)).Distinct());
        HashSet<int> secondOuterIds = new HashSet<int>(GetSecondOuterList().Select(outer => outer.Id).Distinct());

        bool isInnerSubset = secondInnerIds.IsSubsetOf(firstInnerIds);
        bool isOuterSubset = secondOuterIds.IsSubsetOf(firstOuterIds);

        Assert.IsTrue(isInnerSubset);
        Assert.IsTrue(isOuterSubset);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ICanSeeWhenInnerAndOuterCollectionsAreNotSubsets()
    {
        HashSet<int> firstInnerIds = new HashSet<int>(GetFirstOuterList().SelectMany(outer => outer.Inners.Select(inner => inner.Id)).Distinct());
        HashSet<int> firstOuterIds = new HashSet<int>(GetFirstOuterList().Select(outer => outer.Id).Distinct());
        HashSet<int> secondInnerIds = new HashSet<int>(GetSecondOuterList().SelectMany(outer => outer.Inners.Select(inner => inner.Id)).Distinct());
        HashSet<int> secondOuterIds = new HashSet<int>(GetSecondOuterList().Select(outer => outer.Id).Distinct());

        firstInnerIds.Clear();
        firstInnerIds.Add(5);
        firstOuterIds.Clear();
        firstOuterIds.Add(5);

        bool isInnerSubset = secondInnerIds.IsSubsetOf(firstInnerIds);
        bool isOuterSubset = secondOuterIds.IsSubsetOf(firstOuterIds);

        Assert.IsFalse(isInnerSubset);
        Assert.IsFalse(isOuterSubset);
    }

   private List<FirstOuter> GetFirstOuterList()  { ... }

   private List<SecondOuter> GetSecondOuterList()  { ... }
```